# generated Resource File contains strange include file

Tags: c++, windows, resources

Visual studio 2013 generates me a Resource.rc in which appeared `#include "winres.h"`, my question is why it is here, and where to find that file? Or it is really necessary to use it? Because now I am not able to compile my application.

```
    // Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Slovak (Slovakia) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_SKY)
LANGUAGE LANG_SLOVAK, SUBLANG_DEFAULT

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // Slovak (Slovakia) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Neutral (Sys. Default) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_NEUSD)
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_SYS_DEFAULT

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Version
//

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 1,0,0,0
 PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,0
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x40004L
 FILETYPE 0x0L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "041b04b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "XXX"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "XXX"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "Frontend"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (C) 2017"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "XXX"
            VALUE "ProductName", "XXX"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x41b, 1200
    END
END

#endif    // Neutral (Sys. Default) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file contains some definitions for Resource Compiler and is added automatically. There is nothing interesting in it, really. Just ignore.

It resides in MFC's 'Include' directory if you still want to look inside.

Comment: I cannot just ignore it, because now I`m not able to compile my application, it cannot find that file.

Comment: If winres.h is not in the MFC 'include' folder then there is an installation problem. Try reinstalling. You can't go without that file.